# LiveData to Observable conversion to use RxJava

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2, android-livedata

By using **`LiveDataReactiveStreams`** one can transform `LiveData` to `Publisher`.
But in order to use **RxJava2** method such as `withLatestFrom` I need to have an `Observable` instead of the `Publisher`. Is there another way to convert Publisher to Observable beside using this (outdated) library - [RxJava<->ReactiveStreams](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaReactiveStreams) ?

Comment: RxJava 2 `Flowable` is a `Publisher` and can work with `Publisher`s. You likely don't have to convert to `Observable`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I managed to do something like this. But I don't know where to put this code in android project structure, since `toPublisher` requires Activity instance.

```
val rxDataPublisher: Publisher<DataSnapshot> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(this@LocationActivity,fireBaseLiveData)

val rxLocationPublisher: Publisher<Location> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(this@LocationActivity, locationLiveData)

val rxFlowable: Flowable<Pair<Location, DataSnapshot>> = Flowable.fromPublisher(rxDataPublisher)
                .withLatestFrom(rxLocationPublisher, BiFunction{t1, t2 -> Pair(t2,t1) })

val flowableToLiveData = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(rxFlowable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Flowable to LiveData

val flowable = Flowable.just(1, 2, 3)
val liveData = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher<Int>(flowable)

// From Live Data to Publisher(Flowable is also publisher)

LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(this, liveData).subscribe(object: Subscriber<Int>{
    override fun onNext(t: Int?) {}

    override fun onComplete() {}

    override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription?) {}

    override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {}
})
```